# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamically created asp table, which have 4 columns. First column is text, second textbox, third and fourth are text. I need to iterate through the table and get the value from textbox. But I am getting this exception when I am trying to get the textbox value : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. I set the cell index as 1 as the textbox is located in second column. How can I get the text from textbox?

```
foreach (TableRow row in this.reading.Rows)
        {
            var textbox = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[1];
            string id = row.Cells[3].Text;

            if (textbox.Text != "")
            {
                double f = Convert.ToDouble(textbox.Text);
                DBConn.update(f, id);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I would debug the code to find out where is the error. It is hard to guess what is going on but, through the code you´ve posted and the error, you have 3 places to looking for: `Cells[1]`,  `Controls[1]` and `row.Cells[3]`. Maybe the textbox is at the 2nd column indeed but the exception is being thrown in `Controls[1]` or `row.Cells[3]`. If you still not find debugging you would have to provide more info (even from any insight you get debugging). Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dime2lo mentions its hard to find the error without debugging / providing more info.

Try instead of assigning textbox to the the 2nd control in the table row assign it to controls and remove your angle brackets.

var controls = row.Cells[1].Controls;

Then iterate through the controls

```
foreach (Control c Controls)
       {
       //Debug in here. 
       }
```

This will at least help you see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've made it work with something similar to yours idea. But now I am stuck on how to get text from row.Cells[3].Text. How can I iterate on that particular column?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in to inspect the Cells value if it doesn't have a value it might not be assigned, if you just want to iterate over all the cells then use : 
       foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells){
                value = cell.Value.ToString();}